# Solving quadratic equation for coefficients with dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns x and y. I know that the graph for the datapoints would be a parabola, so the function for this dataframe would be `ax²+bx+c=y`.

I read different posts about solving a quadratic function for their variables via numpy. But in this situtation i knew the variables due to the dataframe.

Is there a function to get the values of the coefficients a, b and c with the help of the x, y values from the dataframe?

Comment: Linear regression

Comment: a quadratic isn't linear

Comment: @chitown88: Linear regression does not mean linear fit.

Comment: ahh yes. I see the difference. I'm interpreting it as line of best fit, as opposed to linear in the parameters. thanks for responsing. good to know, and I apologize for my ignorance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use NumPy's `polyfit` to make the polynomial fit and get the fit coefficients. Below is a minimal working answer

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4,5], 
                  'y':[0.9, 3.8, 9.2, 15.4, 25.5]})

fit = np.polyfit(df['x'], df['y'], 2)
equation = np.poly1d(fit)
print ("The fit coefficients are a = {0:.4f}, b = {1:.4f} c = {2:.4f}".format(*fit))
print (equation)
```

**Output**

```
The fit coefficients are a = 1.0857, b = -0.4343 c = 0.3200
       2
1.086 x - 0.4343 x + 0.32
```

You can also visualize the fit using `matplotlib`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xmesh = np.linspace(min(df['x']), max(df['x']), 100)

plt.plot(df['x'], df['y'], 'bo', label='data')
plt.plot(xmesh, equation(xmesh), '-b', label='fit')
plt.legend(fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('x', fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('y', fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use `.polyfit`, and the degree is 2

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3,  4,  5])
y = np.array([4, 7, 12, 19, 28, 39])
z = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)

a = z[0].round(2)
b = z[1].round(2)
c = z[2].round(2)

print ('a: %.1f\nb: %.1f\nc: %.1f' %(a,b,c))
print ('y = %.1fx\u00b2 + %.1fx + %.1f' %(a,b,c))
print ('f(x) = %.1fx\u00b2 + %.1fx + %.1f' %(a,b,c))
```

**Output:**

```
a: 1.0
b: 2.0
c: 4.0
y = 1.0x² + 2.0x + 4.0
f(x) = 1.0x² + 2.0x + 4.0
```